# Install RKWard from Ubuntu repos: "The following packages have unmet dependencies."

Tags: apt, 18.04, dependencies, lts, r

I'm trying to install `RKward` from the Ubuntu repositories, under Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
Unfortunately I'm getting: `The following packages have unmet dependencies.`, as I'm missing `r-api-3.4` which apparently is not in the repo. Searching online, this should be provided by `r-base-core`, which I have installed.

No packages are on hold (`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns nothing) and of course the system is up to date and with no packages to `autoremove`.

How to fix this?

More info:

```
#> apt update
Hit:1 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/archive-ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/archive-ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/archive-ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                                                    
Hit:4 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/security-ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                                    
Ign:5 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/sublimetext apt/dev/ InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:6 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/skype-deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                   
Get:7 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/spotify stable InRelease [3316 B]                                                                                                            
Hit:8 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/nextcloud-devs-ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:9 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/chrome-deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:10 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/teamviewer stable InRelease                                                                                                                 
Hit:11 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/nodejs bionic InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:12 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/libreoffice bionic InRelease                                                                                                                      
Hit:13 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/sublimetext apt/dev/ Release                                                                                                                      
Hit:14 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/chrome-deb stable Release                                                                                                                         
Ign:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                     
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                                       
Hit:18 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                      
Hit:20 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                        
Fetched 3316 B in 1s (2773 B/s)                                                    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
24 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

```
#> apt install rkward
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rkward : Depends: r-api-3.4
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
#> apt-cache policy rkward
rkward:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.7.0-1
  Version table:
     0.7.0-1 500
        500 http://**my company's repo, synced daily**/apt/archive-ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: @RakibFiha Mh, could be. This would however mean that this is a 16 months old unresolved dependency issue in the official Ubuntu repositories, where an official package simply cannot be installed. How can this be true?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1191971/edit) your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt install rkward` and of `apt-cache policy rkward`

Comment: @user535733 Done, thanks. I realise that I have a repo `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/` (I think it provides `Rstudio`) which might be the root cause of this.

Comment: @AF7 that does indeed like the most likely culprit to try first. That usually means uninstalling all packages from that repo, disabling the repo, running `sudo apt update` to refresh the package database without the repo, and then re-installing those packages from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. Always wise to take good notes in case you must undo something - lists of packages are notoriously hard to remember properly. A data backup before starting never hurts, too.